# Sed regex and special chars ( \200 ) which are not matched by the dot

Tags: regex, sed

My problem is that the regex `.*` doesn't seem to match specials characters which appear like:

```
\200
\201
\202
...
```

(in `emacs`).

I have a file with some values between separators like:

```
[a].[b]
```

and I want to display them like this :

```
a=b
```

so I use a regex :

```
sed 's/^\[\(.*\)\]\.\[\(.*\)\]/\1=\2/g' toto
```

It works but when the characters between the `[]` are characters like `\200` `sed` doesn't work, as if `.*` doesn't match those characters.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried using extended regexes (sed -r)?

Comment: no, I don't know it, i'll read the man

Comment: Also, have you tried to use complemented character classes instead of `.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use perl:

```
perl -pe 's,^\[([^]]+)\]\.\[([^]]+)\],$1=$2,' toto
```

Comment: The complemented characters method don't work. and the first method is not I want to do because of some exceptions...

Answer (score 1):

in Emacs:

M-x query-replace-regexp

RET

\[\(.*\)] \.\[\(.*\)]

RET

\1=\2

RET